# Auto Resize image with browser

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am creating a website and i am using carousel bootstrap, the website is mobile friendly, however the only problem I have got is that the slider images do not shrink with the image, so it ends up making them look stretched out. I have tried max-width and max-height 100% but it does not work any advise? I have used

```
<class="img-responsive">
```

but still it does not work. I have amended fiddle if anyone would like to have a go and see what it could be. I have removed the height `500px` but still no luck.

If you resize your browser you will get what I mean, the header height does not shrink.

This is an example of the index page:

http://pastebin.ca/2648252

This is my css

http://pastebin.ca/2648251

Code was too long to post here, Can be seen on there no download required.

Thanks.

Fiddle code: [jsfiddle.net/K56hT/5](http://jsfiddle.net/K56hT/5)

when you shrink the browser with the img responsive. It pushes the image out of the window when resizing.

Comment: have you tried different medias ? `@media(max-width:550px){...} ?`

Comment: I did check your fiddle, but it was ok for me. I mean, the image was resizing automatically.

Comment: you can check the live version www.talktimeonline.co.uk

Answer (score 0):

The main banner looks like it is resizing OK on the example. Please could you provide further info to explain the issue? Depending on the screen size, the banner does get lost behind your top navigation, but that is a result of the absolute positioning.

** UPDATE **

I've added a new fiddle, which will hopefully show it working as you need, without the grey box. Probably worth you comparing your original CSS and HTML to the fiddle to identify all changes and ensure I haven't removed anything you had in there for other reasons, but the key changes were to CSS positioning on the carousel and removing the fixed heights you had on .carousel and .carousel inner classes.

```
.carousel {
  margin-bottom: 60px;
}

.carousel .item {
  background-color: #777;
}

.carousel-inner > .item > img {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Does it do the trick?

http://jsfiddle.net/LSBFd/2/

Comment: Yes it has sorted the auto sizing issue, however the grey box below that looks unprofessional. I have tried getting rid of it by remove the height, however my full image disappears. Any idea why?

Comment: You could add a fixed div around the entire block and then use absolute positioning to display the contents. Easier to demo than explain... Here is a previous fiddle from another user that shows the idea: http://jsfiddle.net/Aj7xg/

Comment: hmm its still the same problem. Here is the fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/K56hT/5/

im trying to get rid of the greybox and image stay where it is. Not possible is it lol?

iv been trying for many days now.

Comment: Updated answer with fiddle... Hope that sorts it for you.

Comment: Did you resolve this @user3365549 with my fiddle example? If so, please mark as answered.

Comment: no i am still working on it.. if you look at my fiddle. the image still goes above and not fixed.

Comment: Do you mean the image in the carousel? If so, the absolute positioning on the "navbar-wrapper" is causing the image to sink behind the menu. If the menu is relative, the image will stay beneath, but you would need to add your green background to the navigation too if retaining the navbar margin.